# Converting date (YYYYMM) formatted as character with no space to date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a csv file with dates as characters in the following format: 202211, 202210, 202209 etc.

I tried using

```
xdate<- as.Date("202211", format="%Y%m")
xdate
```

but the output I get is `NA`

This works if the format would be 20221111

```
xdate<- as.Date("20221111", format="%Y%m%d")  
xdate
```

`[1] "2022-11-11"`

Is there a way to solve this problem without adding a day to the dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your date is always the first day of month, then you can paste "01" at the end of the string and then apply `as.Date`

```
  xdate<- as.Date(paste0("202211", "01"), format="%Y%m%d")
  xdate
[1] "2022-11-01"
```

Comment: Completing the input data to represent _year_ and _month_ and _day_ is likely the best approach.  I actually think R does the right thing here returning `NA` in what is an incomplete date.

Answer (score 2):

Using lubridate avoids manually adding a day to the dates:

```
library(lubridate)
ym("202211")
[1] "2022-11-01"
```